# Folder Observer - On created only runs new script once

Tags: python, observers

Currently I have a folder observer that basically checks whether a new file is added and then should run another Python script for some other executions. The other python script basically transforms a csv into an Excel Table format.
The problem is that the first run/try it does everything it supposed to after a file enters the folder, but whenever a second file is added.... it just ignores to run the other Python script.
What am I missing?

The observer:

````
def on_created(event):
    print(f"Hey, {event.src_path} has been created!\n")
    print(f"The other Python file will now be run\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    import TableRun

def on_deleted(event):
    print(f"What the f**k! Someone deleted {event.src_path}!\n")

def on_modified(event):
    print(f"Hey hey hey, {event.src_path} has been modified \n")

def on_moved(event):
    print(f"Ok ok ok, someone moved {event.src_path} to {event.dest_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = "*"
    ignore_patterns = ""
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)
    my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
    my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
    my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
    my_event_handler.on_moved = on_moved
    path = str(current_path+"String of path")
    go_recursively = True
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)
    my_observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
    my_observer.join()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file only ever gets imported once.  The first time you run `import TableRun` the code loads and executes, but every other time you hit that statement it's a no-op.

The proper solution is to move your `import` statement to the top of your code, rewrite `TableRun` so that it does not execute code on `import`, and replace your existing `import` statement with a function call.  For example:

```
import TableRun


def on_created(event):
    print(f"Hey, {event.src_path} has been created!\n")
    print(f"The other Python file will now be run\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    TableRun.do_something_with_the_file()
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, sounds very reasonable! But what options are there for the .do_something_with_the_file() ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.